# incompatible types: fmonday cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android

Проблема с фрагментом, в котором имеется `ListView`, а он отображает данные из БД.

В `MainActivity` жалуется на третью строчку из кода ниже:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter vpadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fmonday(), "Понедельник");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new ftuesday(), "Вторник");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fwednesday(), "Среда");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fthursday(), "Четверг");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new ffriday(), "Пятница");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fsaturday(), "Суббота");
    viewPager.setAdapter(vpadapter);
}
```

Фрагмент объявлен так:

```
public class fmonday extends FragmentActivity  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
```

Logcat:

> Error:(98, 27) error: incompatible types: fmonday cannot be converted to Fragment

Гугл посоветовал поменять в объявлении класса "fmonday" `extends FragmentActivity` на `extends Fragment`, но после этого у меня появляется несколько других ошибок, одна с Loader-ом фрагмента, вторая непонятна:

> error: cannot find symbol method getSupportLoaderManager()
>
> error: onDestroy() in fmonday cannot override onDestroy() in Fragment attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public.

Полный код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter vpadapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fmonday(), "Понедельник");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new ftuesday(), "Вторник");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fwednesday(), "Среда");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fthursday(), "Четверг");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new ffriday(), "Пятница");
    vpadapter.addFrag(new fsaturday(), "Суббота");
    viewPager.setAdapter(vpadapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Полный код fmonday:

```
public class fmonday extends FragmentActivity  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
ListView lvData1;
DB db;
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fmonday);

    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();

    // формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] {
            //DB.COLUMN_IMG,
            DB.COLUMN_TXT,
            DB.COLUMN_PREP,
            DB.COLUMN_AUD1,//DB.COLUMN_AUD
    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
            //R.id.ivImg,
            R.id.tvTextPredmet,
            R.id.tvTextPrepod,
            R.id.tvTextAud,
            //R.id.tvTextAud
    };

    // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
    lvData1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData1.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
    registerForContextMenu(lvData1);
    // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

// обработка нажатия кнопки
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    // добавляем запись
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Adding.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
    String name1 = data.getStringExtra("name1");
    String name2 = data.getStringExtra("name2");
    db.addRec(name,
            name1,
            name2);
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
        db.delRec(acmi.id);
        // получаем новый курсор с данными
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем подключение при выходе
    db.close();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}

static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    DB db;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

}
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Гугл посоветовал поменять в объявлении класса "fmonday" extends
>   FragmentActivity на extends Fragment

Правильно посоветовал. `FragmentActivity` это не фрагмент, это `Activity`.

Вам нужно `FragmentActivity` заменить на `Fragment`, а где выпадают ошибки - поправить.